# Wait for onMounted() to finish inside test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In my setup I perform a couple of functions inside the `onMounted` function. In my test I want to wait for these to finish. How can I achieve that?

I tried using the `nextTick` and the `flushPromises`(even though there aren't any promises) but none of them work.

Here is some example code:

Vue Component:

```js
setup() {
  const mounted = ref(false);
  onMounted(() => {
    mounted.value = true;
  })
}
```

Test:

```js
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent)
  it('expects mounted to be true after mount', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.mounted).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get an error. The test just fails because the 'mounted' variable is still false when running the test

Comment: If the test fails, there's an error. Please, list it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing is exporting the data once the component has been setup:

```
setup() {
  const mounted = ref(false);
  onMounted(() => {
    mounted.value = true;
  })

  return { mounted };
}
```